# Config nginx to domain access react app subpath route

Tags: nginx, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to configure an additional domain to access a route from a React application.

It is not a subdomain, it is a domain and it needs to do with all requests from that domain direct to /painel

Currently the main domain is like this:

```
server {

    server_name domain.com.br www.domain.com.br;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5400s;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5400s;
    }

    location /arquivos/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5400s;
    }
}
```

This is what I configured for the other domain

```
server {

    server_name anotherdomain.com.br www.anotherdomain.com.br;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/painel;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5400s;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5400s;
    }

    location /arquivos/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 5400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5400s;
    }
}
```

But always return blank page with this errors:

[image: error print]

I tried using rewrite, adding slashes to the end of the proxy_pass, but it doesn't work.

I appreciate any help

Comment: How about changing `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/painel;` to something like `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;`?

Comment: Why change the port? The React application is on this reverse proxy, on port 3000. The only thing I want is for the other domain to directly access the application's route /painel, and for all requests in that domain to access from that route.